# Как получить разницу в координатах GPS зная центр и радиус

Tags: yandex-places-api

Как можно получить разницу в координатах GPS между центром и точкой лежащий на окружности, если даны координаты центра и радиус окружности

upd. Разница в координатах нужна по модулю, точку можно взять любую, например лежащую на 0°

Comment: Разница в координатах это что?

Comment: На окружности бесконечное число точек, так что нужно уточнение.